The option to change video quality in videojs is not functioning properly on iPhone and Mac Safari browser
I have added the option to change the video quality in the video player. It works in Chrome and Windows browsers but it is not working in iPhone and Mac Safari, only the button shows, and options are not visible. Can anyone help me with this issue?
<video-js id="my-video" class="vjs-fluid" controls playsinline autoplay muted>
    <source src="https://3d26876b73d7.us-west-2.playback.live-video.net/api/video/v1/us-west-2.913157848533.channel.rkCBS9iD1eyd.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video-js>
<script src="node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/videojs-hls-quality-selector/dist/videojs-hls-quality-selector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myDoubleClickHandler(event) {
        // `this` refers to the player in this context
        this.pause();
    }
</script>
<script type="module">
    var player = videojs('my-video', {
        autoplay: 'muted',
        techOrder: ['html5'], // Force non-native HLS playback
        enableSmoothSeeking: true,
        sources: [{
            src: 'https://3d26876b73d7.us-west-2.playback.live-video.net/api/video/v1/us-west-2.913157848533.channel.rkCBS9iD1eyd.m3u8',
        }],
        // playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
        

        // disablePictureInPicture: true,
        enableSmoothSeeking: true,
        liveui: true,

        userActions: {
            // click: false,
            doubleClick: myDoubleClickHandler,
            hotkeys: function(event) {
                if (event.which === 32) {
                    if (this.paused()) {
                        this.play();
                    } else {
                        this.pause();
                    }
                }
            },
            // controlBar: {
            //     skipButtons: {
            //       forward: 5,
            //       backward: 10
            //     }
            // },

        },
    });
    (function (window, videojs) {
      // var examplePlayer = window.examplePlayer = videojs('my-video');
      var hlsQualitySelector = window.hlsQualitySelector = player.hlsQualitySelector({
        displayCurrentQuality: false,
      });
    }(window, window.videojs));
</script>

Video quality option

A quality selector can only work with MSE playback. Video.js uses native playback by default on desktop Safari. iOS doesn't support MSE.
To use MSE on desktop Safari, include html5: {vhs: { overrideNative: true }} in the player options. On iOS this isn't currently possible.
